# output array into a new div named "row" after 4 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am currently using bootstrap and wanted my output to be in a certain grid. So for that I need to group my array into piles of 3 and put them into a div with the classname "row". The grouping of the array is done, but I don't know how to go on from here, because  is not rendered anymore and I only render 1 element in a row atm..

Array:

```
const itemsToRender = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '6',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }]
```

Grouping:

```
function splitArrayIntoChunks(arr, chunkLen){
  var chunkList = []
  var chunkCount = Math.ceil(arr.length/chunkLen)
  for(var i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++){
      chunkList.push(arr.splice(0, chunkLen))
  }
  return chunkList}

var chunks = splitArrayIntoChunks(itemsToRender, 3)
```

Component Code:

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      {itemsToRender.map(item => (
      <Item key={item.id} item={item}/>
      ))}
    </div>
 </div>
 )
```

My desired result should like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">1</div>
            <div class="col">2</div>
            <div class="col">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">4</div>
            <div class="col">5</div>
            <div class="col">6</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post an example of the desired result?

Comment: sure, updated the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method of dividing array into chucks using [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
Note that `.slice` unlike [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is **not mutating** the original array.

It will look Something like this:

```
const makeChunks = (array = [], numOfChuncks = 1) => {
  let chunks = [];
  let currentChunck = 0;

  while (currentChunck < array.length) {
    chunks.push(array.slice(currentChunck, currentChunck += numOfChuncks));
  }

  return chunks;
}
```

---

Here is a running example:

```js
const makeChunks = (array = [], numOfChuncks = 1) => {
  let chunks = [];
  let currentChunck = 0;

  while (currentChunck < array.length) {
    chunks.push(array.slice(currentChunck, currentChunck += numOfChuncks));
  }

  return chunks;
}


const itemsToRender = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'Item2',
  image: 'item1.png'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'Item3',
  image: 'item1.png'
}, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'Item4',
  image: 'item1.png'
}, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'Item5',
  image: 'item1.png'
}, {
  id: '6',
  name: 'Item6',
  image: 'item1.png'
}];

const groupedBy3 = makeChunks(itemsToRender, 3);

const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <div className="col-xs-3">{item.name}</div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {Object.keys(groupedBy3).map(key => {
          return (
            <div key={key} className="row">
              {
                groupedBy3[key].map(item => (<Item key={item.id} item={item} />))
              }
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this function:

```
const rows = items.map((x,i) => {
  return i % 3 === 0 ? items.slice(i, i+3) : null;
}).filter(x => x != null);
```

See it in action with Bootstrap below

```js
const items = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }, {
  id: '6',
  name: 'Item1',
  image: 'item1.png'
  }]

const App = () => {
  const rows = items.map((x,i) => {
      return i % 3 === 0 ? items.slice(i, i+3) : null;
  }).filter(x => x != null);

  return (
    <div>
      {rows.map((row, index) => {
        return (<div className="row" key={index}>
          {row.map(col => <div className="col-4">{col.name}</div>)}
        </div>);
       })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
span {
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root"></div>
```